# Last Week Tonight Tv-Show featured integral

Tags: integration

In an episode of Last Week Tonight With John Oliver he was discussing standardised tests. While the segment was really funny and interesting I was a bit distracted due to an image shown as an illustration.

[image: I have provided a screenshot here]

It was an image of a blackboard with an integral written on it. It looked like this:

$$\int \sqrt{a^2 - x^2} dx = \frac{x}{2}$$

I found myself staring at this, wondering what they mean. I solved the integral using trig-substitution. I ended up with an answer involving an inverse trig-function. I tried rewriting it but in no way was it going to be $\frac{x}{2}$.

I also noticed that they did not add the constant of integration (+c) at the end, which made me think it was a question rather than an equality. Like: For which value of a is the expression equal to $\frac{x}{2}$. But this did not make much sense to me either.

Therefore my question is: Is this wrong and just used as something that “looks like” math? And if not, is this a question rather than just a ‘statement’? If so, is it solvable?

Comment: One shouldn't generally look for logic in places one did not lose it

Comment: It could be a "true or false" question.